# Unable to run animation

Tags: jquery, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Trying to run animation through loop, build succeeds but fails to perform animation on simulator, below is the code supposed to perform animation

```
      NSMutableArray *frames = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
//supposed to loop through file names a0001 to a0010 from texture file.
            for (int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
                NSString *frameName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"a%04i.png",i];
                [frames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:frameName]];
                }
// set the frame speed 
            CCAnimation *a =[CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:frames delay:1.0f/24.0f];

// supposed to use restoreoriginalframe method after actionwithanimation but since it is deprecated removed it

            [mole runAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:a]];
```

Any help is highly appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is how I accomplish the same thing.  The only difference I can see if that I do not load my images into an array, but instead these are textures that were loaded into memory using a sprite sheet.

```
NSString * animateCycle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ImageName 00%%02d.png"];
```

The image names would be along the lines of "ImageName 0001.png", "ImageName 0002.png", and so on.

```
CCActionInterval * action = [CCAnimate actionWithSpriteSequence:animateCycle numFrames:8 delay:.1 restoreOriginalFrame:YES];
[mySprite runAction:action];
```

This will cycle through the images based on the designated delay.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the help, im following lynda.com videos, if possible could you help identify what is wrong with the current code. Im trying to stick to authors code as close as possible for better understanding of coming chapters.

Comment: Are you saying that it runs on a device but not on the simulator?

Comment: No I mean its not doing the animation.i just displays the first frame image. Ideally  its supposed to run through a series of frames from texture and display animation.

Comment: If you have not already done so, confirm that the actual frame names that your "stringWithFormat" is creating to ensure that they match the names of the images that you loaded into memory.

Comment: The format is correct it worked for author in the video and files I'm using are same as used by author. It works perfectly in the video i have the exact same code but doesnt work for me, though the versions are different , author in the video as 1.. version with xcode 4. I have xcode 5 with cocos 2d version 2.. because my mac didnt allow me to install version 1..im not sure if change in version is causing this problem, the only difference is on the last line of code right after ccanimate call he added restoreoriginalframe method, which is not available in cocs2d.